# Add new class to existing class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2mp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#next").click(function() {
        $(".slideshow-inner").nextAll("div.item").addClass(".active");
        $(".item.active").css({display: "block"});

    });
});
```

Why doesn't this do anything!? My code should add ".active" class to already existing classes and when it does, the newly founded ".item.class" should be displayed. But it doesn't want to add a new class...

Comment: If you read the `nextAll` documentation page you'll find the answer: `Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.`. You're looking for [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). You also just need to pass the class name when you use `addClass()` so you can remove the `.`.

Comment: Already answered but since I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2mp/4/

Comment: You can reduce that selector to simply `$(".slideshow-inner .item").addClass("active")`

Comment: thanks both of you, those are the two mistakes I was loking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.addClass()** accepts a string of one or more classes, not a selector.

You should be using:

```
$(".slideshow-inner").nextAll("div.item").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

.item divs are not siblings of slideshow-inner.
Look like you are looking for find() instead of nextAll().